# Extract entity from dataframe using spacy

Tags: python, pandas, spacy

[image]I read contents from excel file using pandas::

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("FAM_template_Update 1911274_JS.xlsx" )
df
```

While trying to extract entities using spacy::

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(df)
for enitity in doc.ents:
     print((entity.text))
```

Got Error:: TypeError: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got DataFrame)

```
        On line(3)-----> doc = nlp(df)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is expected as `Spacy` is not prepared to deal with a dataframe as-is. You need to do some work before being able to print the entities. Start by identifying the column that contains the text you want to use `nlp` on. After that, extract its value as list, and now you're ready to go. Let's suppose the column name that contains the text is named `Text`.

```
for i in df['Question'].tolist():
    doc = nlp(i)
    for entity in doc.ents:
         print((entity.text))
```

This will iterate over each text (row) for in your dataframe and print the entities.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the individual strings within your dataframe. The NLP parser and entity extraction is expecting a string.

For example:

```
for row in range(len(df)):
    doc = nlp(df.loc[row, "text_column"])
    for enitity in doc.ents:
         print((entity.text))
```

Comment: It gives me error :: ValueError: cymem.cymem.Pool has the wrong size, try recompiling. Expected 64, got 48

code::

    import spacy
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
    for row in range(len(df)):
        doc = nlp(df.loc[row,"Question"])
        for entity in doc.ents:
            print((entity.text))

Comment: @ajax The loop works for me on my dataset. It looks like you have a secondary problem. https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref/issues/102. Try re-installing Spacy.

Comment: Yes so downgrading spacy worked for me. So it gives me entities of Question column as per the image provided.But its not giving me every text. It gave me wikipage but just above is wikisphere that it didnot provide.

Comment: What it can recognize is based on the library that it is built on. It also has to do with a bunch of things, such as position of speech, capitalization, etc. E.g. it detects: `Wikipedia, USA, Canada, Apple` for `"I used Wikipedia to get answers about USA and then also Canada and how they like Apple"` but only detects `USA Canada` for `"wikipedia USA Canada Apple"`

Comment: say if  spacy cannot recognize entity present I want to print the question as it is. can i use if statement and just print if entity not present print the question as it is?

how to approach this problem?