# Extracting the entities from Spacy and putting in new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, spacy

So I followed the answer in this question ([Extract entity from dataframe using spacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60116419/extract-entity-from-dataframe-using-spacy)) and that solved me being able to iterate on a DF.

Issues I am facing is trying to take these results, add a column from original df then put all this into a new df. I want the DOI from original df, the entity text and entity labels from the NER.

Code to grab and put into list:

```
entities=[]
nlp = spacy.load("en_ner_bionlp13cg_md")
for i in df['Abstract'].tolist():
    doc = nlp(i)
    for entity in doc.ents:
        entities.append((df.DOI, entity.text , entity.label_))
```

Then I take the entities list and feed into a new df:

```
df_ner = pd.DataFrame.from_records(entities, columns =['DOI', 'ent_name', 'ent_type'])
```

Unfortunately, only the first records gets loaded into the df. What am i missing?

```
DOI ent_name    ent_type
0   3 10.7501/j.issn.0253-2670.2020.... COVID-19    GENE_OR_GENE_PRODUCT
1   3 10.7501/j.issn.0253-2670.2020.... ACE2    GENE_OR_GENE_PRODUCT
2   3 10.7501/j.issn.0253-2670.2020.... angiotensin converting enzyme II    GENE_OR_GENE_PRODUCT
3   3 10.7501/j.issn.0253-2670.2020.... ACE2    GENE_OR_GENE_PRODUCT
4   3 10.7501/j.issn.0253-2670.2020.... UniProt GENE_OR_GENE_PRODUCT
```

Comment: Hi Sean, welcome to the site! What do you get if you print out `df['Abstract'].tolist()`?

Comment: Hi @forgetso..Thanks!

Here is the output of that. I shortened the text to be a bit more readable:
['this is an abstract talking about COVID-19','
' 'here is another abstract COVID-19 and the ACE2 gene','
' 'finally, the last abstract talking about liver, lung, pulmonary system, heart']

Comment: @forgetso the NER appears to be grabbing all the terms but wont add the proper DOI to each record

Comment: Can you let me know what df is equal to? It's not shown in your code.

Comment: df=pd.read_csv('./data/CDC/All_Articles_Excel_.csv',encoding='ISO-8859-1', usecols=["Abstract","Title"])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
getattr(tqdm, '_instances', {}).clear()  # ⬅ clear the progress
spacy.prefer_gpu()
nlp = spacy.load("en_ner_bionlp13cg_md")
entities=[]
uuid = str(df.uuid)
for i in tqdm(df['Abstract'].tolist(),bar_format="{l_bar}%s{bar}%s{r_bar}" % (Fore.GREEN, Fore.RESET)):
    doc = nlp(i)
    for entity in doc.ents:
        entities.append((i, entity.text, entity.label_, uuid))
```