# How to extract Named Entities from Pandas DataFrame using SpaCy

Tags: python, pandas, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to extract Named Entities using first answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60116419/extract-entity-from-dataframe-using-spacy) question and code is as following

```
for i in df['Article'].to_list():
    doc = nlp(i)
    for entity in doc.ents:
        print((entity.text))
```

But it is not printing entities. I have tried `print(i)` and `print(doc)` both variables have values and `df['Article']` contains news text. Can someone help with why second loop is not extracting entities? Thank you

EDIT:
This is [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1toRNl-UgBIm5-E6DRfkl7t-lkz5PakOD/view?usp=sharing) file, please run following code to form preprocessing that I have done.

```
df.iloc[:,0].dropna(inplace=True)
df = df[df.iloc[:,0].notna()]
```

to remove special characters from `df['Articles']`

```
df['Article'] = df['Article'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', '', x))
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the text in the df["Article"] column? What you have there looks correct - I'm curious if there are no named entities to be found.

Comment: I have added google drive link to csv file and steps that I performed to preprocess raw dataset

Comment: With `df['Article'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', '', x))`, you remove all whitespace. I think you want `df['Article'] = df['Article'].str.replace(r'(?:_|[^\w\s])+', '')` to remove all special chars.

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor Stribizew that was the problem with my code now it is extracting entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `df['Article'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\W+', '', x))`, you remove all whitespace chars from your articles.

You need to use

```py
df['Article'] = df['Article'].str.replace(r'(?:_|[^\w\s])+', '')
```

With that regex, you will only remove special chars other than whitespaces.